# Local Container Registry using S3 Bucket and Proxy Server

Tags: proxy, docker, amazon-s3

I am trying to deploy a local docker registry on AWS EC2 instances.  The instances must reach out through a foraward proxy (apache) server. However, I am unable to reach the s3 bucket from within the running registry container instance.  My docker registry instance configuration is as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
  localRegistry:
    image: registry:2
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./auth:/auth
    environment:
      - "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd"
      - "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=MyRealm"
      - "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd"
      - "REGISTRY_STORAGE=s3"
      - "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_REGION={{ s3Region }}"
      - "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET={{ s3BucketName }}"
      - "REGISTRY_STORAGE_CACHE_BLOBDESCRIPTOR=inmemory"
      - "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ACCESSKEY={{ s3UserAccessID }}"
      - "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECRETKEY={{ s3UserAccessKey }}"
      - "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ROOTDIRECTORY=/registry"
      - "REGISTRY_MIDDLEWARE_REDIRECT_BASEURL={{ proxyServerURL }}"
    restart: always
```

I can reach the S3 Bucket with the user using AWS CLI on the HOST.  I've disabled SELinux on the host.  The error message from the container is

```
localRegistry1  | time="2019-09-26T13:48:04.873569714Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" auth.user.name=<USER> err.code=unknown err.detail="s3aws: RequestError: send request failed
localRegistry1  | caused by: Put https://<s3BucketName>.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/ubuntu/_uploads/34732c55-6be3-4741-bfa8-e084708eb2a1/startedat: dial tcp <s3BucketIP>:443: i/o timeout" err.message="unknown error" go.version=go1.11.2 http.request.host="localhost:5000" http.request.id=<requestID> http.request.method=POST http.request.remoteaddr="<docker0_iface_addr>:46102" http.request.uri="/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/" http.request.useragent="docker/19.03.2 go/go1.12.8 git-commit/6a30dfc kernel/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.2 \(linux\))" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=2m0.357571388s http.response.status=500 http.response.written=104 vars.name=ubuntu 
localRegistry1  | <docker0_iface_addr> - - [26/Sep/2019:13:46:04 +0000] "POST /v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 500 104 "" "docker/19.03.2 go/go1.12.8 git-commit/6a30dfc kernel/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.2 \\(linux\\))"
```

I'm thinking it could be an issue with aws security groups between the Forward proxy ec2 server and the docker host instance.  However, I'm not quite sure what that would need to be.

Comment: When I take the S3 backend configuration options out I am able to push to a local volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was staring me in the face.  Add HTTP(S)_PROXY to the container environment variables.

```
version: '3'
services:
  localRegistry:
    image: registry:2
    ports:
      - .....
    volumes:
      - .....
    environment:
      ......
      - "HTTP_PROXY={{ proxyServerURL }}"
      - "HTTPS_PROXY={{ proxyServerURL }}"
    restart: always
```